# Linux is not executing command by Java

Tags: java, linux, bash, runtime

I am trying to run some servers from a bot, but I can't get it run my screen and host the server. I've tried debugging and getting some kind of code to debug, but I come up with nothing. Maybe it's something in my syntax?

These are the value you can run in: name = factorio, path = /opt/factorio/bin/x64/factorio, args = --start-server map.zip

Together makes:

`screen -dmS factorio -m bash -c "/opt/factorio/bin/x64/factorio --start-server map.zip"`

```
public boolean run() {

        try {
            System.out.println("screen -dmS "+serverName+" -m bash -c \""+path+" "+args+"\"");
            Process proc = rt.exec("screen -dmS "+serverName+" -m bash -c \""+path+" "+args+"\"");

            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
            String str = null;
            while ( (str = read.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(str);
            try {
                proc.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Exit value: "+proc.exitValue());
            this.setStatus(ONLINE);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could run your server command directly without passing it throw screen. Screen is a terminal multiplexer, which allows a user to access multiple separate terminal sessions inside a single terminal window.

Comment: @PascalFares So I could just do `/opt/factorio/bin/x64/factorio --start-server map.zip` and it'll run it for me? Will it tie up my java thread? Will I have access to the process stdIn (Screen doesn't let me, so this will be a plus)?

Comment: If you run `screen -dmS factorio -m bash -c "/opt/factorio/bin/x64/factorio --start-server map.zip"` on it's own, does it make the screen and start the server?

Comment: If I manually execute in putty, yes, if I go from my program, no.